# Mongodb $lookup return empty array as result

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

Two schemas I am using for aggregate

- First Collection

  **Users** have **_id as Objectid()**
- Second Collection

  **UsersDetails**  have **userId as String**. It is giving me empty array resultant.
  Is there any way to join two collections by matching object and string?

  ```
   Users.aggregate ([
      {
        $lookup:
          {
            from: "UsersDetails",
            localField: '_id',  //  ---- ObjectId("111112112321321")
            foreignField:  "userId",  //----- String  "111112112321321"
            as: 'resultdata'
          }
      }
    ]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this cannot be done. There is an open request for that so feel free to vote: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781

You will need to either join on the client side or convert your data which seems like the better option to me.